# How to make Gridview dynamic in android?

Tags: android

How do I make a `GridView` dynamic in android?

I want a grid that automatically displays on screen when WiFi devices get scanned. I tried a static `GridView` but now what I want is to use a dynamic `GridView`.

Comment: Elaborate what you actually mean by Dynamic Gridview

Comment: Please post your GridView adapter code.

Comment: Show the samle UI what you want

Comment: suppose we have one button wifi and if i click on that button then i want to list available wifi devices in grid....like x wifi device in one grid with any image,y in another grid...means i want automatically display that devices suppose there are 2 devices then only 2 grids will be shown on screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a `GridView` with an empty Adapter attached to it. By empty I mean one which returns 0 in `getCount()`. You may want to set Visibility of the `GridView` to `View.GONE` also, but this is optional.

Then, when you receive the data to display (e.g. devices got scanned) you simply add the data to the Adapter, call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on it and set Visibility of the `GridView` to `View.VISIBLE`.

Do the above each time the data set changes/updates :-)

Comment: can u plz send me some example regarding this..i am new in android